# Why is jQuery not getting this value?

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery to grab values of the form and make an AJAX POST call and post the values to a .php file, which processes the values into the db.

Whenever I try to test with`alert()` if I got the value, everything works except the stock value... I can't find what I'm doing wrong..

jQuery:

```
var title = $("#title").val();
var text = $("#text").val();
var summary = $("#description").val();
var keywords = $("#keywords").val();
var price = $("#price").val();
var stock = $("#stock").val();
var brand = $("#brand").val();

var product = product;

alert(title);
alert(stock);
```

The form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal form-inline">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="title">Product:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title" placeholder="Enter new title">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="price">Price:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price" name="price" placeholder="Enter new price">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="stock">Stock:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="stock" name="stock" placeholder="Enter new stock">
            </div>
            <div class='form-group'>
                <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="text">Text:</label>
                <textarea class='form-control' rows='5' id='text' name='text' placeholder='Enter new text'></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="description">Description:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" name="description" placeholder="Enter new description">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="brand">Brand:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="brand" name="brand" placeholder="Enter new brand">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-3"  for="keywords">Keywords:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="keywords" name="keywords" placeholder="Enter new keywords">
            </div>
            <a href="#" id="updateProductRecord" pid="<?php echo $pro_id; ?>"><button type="submit" id="submitUpdateProduct" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button></a>
            </form>
```

Comment: Can you make your question clear? or add a fiddle to understand

Comment: nvm fixed it, used the same id somewhere else before.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<form class="form-horizontal form-inline">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="title">Product:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title" value="1" placeholder="Enter new title">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="price">Price:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price" name="price" placeholder="Enter new price">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="stock">Stock:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="stock" name="stock" value="2" placeholder="Enter new stock">
            </div>
            <div class='form-group'>
                <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="text">Text:</label>
                <textarea class='form-control' rows='5' id='text' name='text' placeholder='Enter new text'></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="description">Description:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" name="description" placeholder="Enter new description">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="brand">Brand:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="brand" name="brand" placeholder="Enter new brand">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-3"  for="keywords">Keywords:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="keywords" name="keywords" placeholder="Enter new keywords">
            </div>
            <a href="#" id="updateProductRecord" pid="<?php echo $pro_id; ?>"><button type="submit" id="submitUpdateProduct" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button></a>
            </form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var title = $("#title").val();
var text = $("#text").val();
var summary = $("#description").val();
var keywords = $("#keywords").val();
var price = $("#price").val();
var stock = $("#stock").val();
var brand = $("#brand").val();

var product = product;

alert(title);
alert(stock);
</script>
```

This code is working fine, i think you are not getting value from php/ajax ..